# when i press F11 to boot from a pendrive my screen stays black

Tags: boot, usb-drive

so here is my problem. I downloaded the ubuntu 20.04 iso image and applied it to my pen drive. I plug in the pen drive, reboot my system, and hit the f11 key at least 4 times. and then, I just get a black screen. it stays stuck in the process of loading the options which would allow me to boot from my pen drive. what do I do? does this have anything to do with installing what some call the ''grub menu''? I'm unaware of what it is exactly.

Comment: It might help if you're specific with details, (*there are more than 30 20.04 ISOs, 20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, ... and each created for server/desktop & many architectures*).  Did you download & write the correct ISO for your *unstated* Ubuntu 20.04 product & architecture?  Did you validate the ISO prior to write? and then the media verify work?  (*using another box if it won't boot on your first box*).  As 20.04 is the 2020-April release of Ubuntu, did you use an original? or newer stack ISO (especially important if you're not using a pre-2020 machine).  Please provide specific details.

Comment: What brand of computer do you have? some brands use ESC, F8, F9, F10 or F12 to choose boot drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the boot image you put on the pen drive was not written correctly. My advice would be to completely re-write it using a tool like Rufus or just using the dd command from another Linux machine. (These seem to be the most reliable methods for me.)

Do *not* use uunetbootin, the windows iso writer, or anything of that nature I've not had consistent results with those and they rarely work out.